# SharePoint 2013 - webpartsandcontrols error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm getting the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'WebPartsAndControls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e2637de7f0074503' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

How should I go about tracking down the issue?

Comment: Where you are getting this error and what action produces this?

Comment: When I view any of my store front pages under my subsite.  It doesn't matter if I am logged into share point or not.

Comment: It seems there is a webpart that is causing this issue. At the end of the page add `contents=1`. This will give you the list of webparts. Remove the webparts you are not using.

Comment: thanks, but when I add that to the URL, it tells me "There are currently no Web Parts associated with any Web Part Zones on this page. Web Parts added to the page outside of a Web Part Zone will not appear in this list."

Comment: Ok in that case open up the corresponding master page & page layout. Check if there is any reference to the assembly `WebPartsAndControls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e2637de7f0074503`

Comment: you are awesome!  that publickeytoken is referencing a custom ASP.NET snippet that I had put in early last week into my custom page layout (which is why the issue is generating anywhere that that this custom page layout is being used.) I simply need to get back with my server side developer to see what is wrong with his user control I believe...thanks Amal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happens because of any of the following issues

1. A webpart that is embedded on the page. To find all webparts add `contents=1` at the end of the page URL
2. Check the Page Layout and see if any reference is there for the mentioned assembly
3. Check the master page and see if any reference is there for the mentioned assmebly